# Problem importing dump file to sql developer

Tags: oracle, file, oracle-sqldeveloper, dump

I'm trying to import a dump file to the oracle sql developer, but it fails. Does anyone know how the directory of the dump file should be defined? I've a feeling that the directory under the file name is indicated wrongly. Does anyone know?

[image: Error importing dump file]

I tried with the command

```
  SQL> select Directory_Path
    2  from all_directories
    3  where directory_name = 'DATA_PUMP_DIR';
```

Result:

```
DIRECTORY_PATH
C:\app\TestKing1/admin/mydb/dpdump/
```

Tried changing the directory with command, but fails.

```
CREATE DIRECTORY DATA_PUMP_DIR AS 'C:\app\TestKing1\admin\mydb\dpdump\'
```

**ERROR FOR CHANGING DIRECTORY**

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
```

**I've added the dump file.**

[Testing file](https://a.uguu.se/7qYmDQVWv6AA_load_departments.dump)

Answer (score 1):

Query your db with the following query:

```
select DIRECTORY_PATH
  from all_directories
 where directory_name = 'DATA_PUMP_DIR';
```

It will give you the path to the default DATA PUMP folder

You may want to create a new directory pointing to your folder:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY custom_dump_dir AS 'c:\app\TestKing1\admin\MYDB\dpdump\';
```

Then use that directory on the data pump export instead of the default one

Comment: I checked and tried changing the directory of data dump, but fails. I tried with CREATE command.. Do you know how to change the directory of the data pump file?

Comment: I've managed to change the directory for the dump file, but it still yields error. Not sure if there is something with the file....I've uploaded the file in my post and if you don't mind, you can also give it a try.

Comment: @user234568 datapump files are usually `.dmp` not `.dump` What's the source of your file?

Answer (score 0):

If the directory is wrongly created, connect as a privileged user (SYS) and re-create it using correct parameters. To do that, use **OR REPLACE**, e.g.

```
create or replace directory data_pump_dir...
```

command